# EmberJs: binding input element from Ember.TextField in the init function (Autocomplete google map)

Tags: ember.js

I try to use the GoogleMap Autocomplete component.
This Google Javascript service needs simply to be binded to an input field.

My idea was to  create a new View extending TextField and do the binding as described bellow:
I have a doubt regarding the "this" in the Autocomplete constructor (this, option).
As you can easily understand,this is for me the input component... (the error it perhaps here)

```
App.AutoCompleAddressView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  type: 'text',
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    var options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
    };
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this, options);
  }
});
```

and the html code template:

```
{{view App.AutoCompleAddressView}}
```

Unfortunately I get an Ember error: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'getAttribute'**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if the google.maps.places.Autocomplete requires a DOM element, then you have to pass this.$() to it. I think you have do to that in the didInsertElement hook. Something like:

```
App.AutoCompleAddressView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  type: 'text',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
    };
 //this.$() return the element as an array form, but google autocomplete seems to not accept this. So take the first one.
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.$()[0], options);
  }
});
```

Added a minimal example: http://jsfiddle.net/6p6XJ/211/

Comment: same error:  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getAttribute'  
YJ
J.$l
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) %7Bmain,places%7D.js:9
(anonymous function) %7Bmain,places%7D.js:24
O %7Bmain,places%7D.js:9
wf but I have found this post (that I not perfectly understand) : http://raditha.com/blog/archives/mixing-google-places-and-jquery-will-lead-to-frustration.html

Comment: updated answer, seems you have to take the first elem from the jquery selector